# Como llamar a get shared preferences desde nav menu

Tags: android, kotlin

Quiero saber como puedo acceder a la clave guardada en shared preferences con el nombre "correo" desde el nav menú para que pueda mostrar el email con el que el usuario inicia sesión:

Ahora mismo lo tengo configurado para que muestre dicha información en una de las activities y lo hace sin problemas con la siguiente función que ejecuto en el oncreate:

```
fun setup(correo: String, proveedor: String) {
emailTextView.text = correo}
```

Edit: También he probado con la siguiente opción con el mismo resultado:

```
fun setup(correo: String, proveedor: String) {
        getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs_file), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
 emailTextView.text = correo
}
```

Este es el código que está guardando ese correo en las sharedpreferences:

```
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs_file), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            prefs.putString("correo", correo)
 prefs.apply()
```

Como he dicho, quiero que se muestre el correo con el que se inicia sesión en mi nav menú, el textview se llama `emailTextView2.text`, he probado a cambiarle el nombre y me da un error `NullPointerException`. Podéis echarme un cable? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el código que suministras estas teniendo problemas con el llamado al SharedPreferences, por lo tanto planteo la siguiente solución.

He de aclarar que con esta respuesta podrás cambiar el mensaje del nav_header el cual en mi caso tiene el id `textview`

Primero en la clase de login, puse un método para guardar el correo en el sharedpreferences, el cual fue el siguiente:

```
private fun Context.setSharedPreference(key: String, value: String) {
    getSharedPreferences(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().apply {
        putString(key, value); apply()
    }
}
```

este método esta siendo llamado dentro del botón de login de la siguiente manera:

```
    button.setOnClickListener {
        setSharedPreference("MAIL", text.text.toString())
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Ahora, en la clase donde tengo el navigation, definí un metodo para realizar el llamado de los valores guardados:

```
private fun Context.getSharedPreference(key: String): String {
    getSharedPreferences(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)?.getString(key, "")?.let { return it }
    return ""
}
```

Este método es llamado dentro del oncreate para poder asignar el valor al header, quedando:

```
    val header: View = navView.getHeaderView(0)
    val email: TextView = header.findViewById(R.id.textView)
    email.text = getSharedPreference("MAIL")
```

De esta manera podemos obtener el correo introducido en el login en esta actividad, y se veria de la siguiente manera:

[image]

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Excelente!!! Funciona!!! Un millón de gracias amigo!!!

Answer (score 0):

En este caso falta que hagas uso del método [**.apply()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()) para guardar el valor de la preferencia:

```
val prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs_file), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
        prefs.putString("correo", correo).apply()
```

Comment: Buenas Jorge, el método .apply() ya lo tengo en mi código, de hecho como comento en la pregunta está mostrando esa información en otro textview correctamente, el problema es cuando quiero que se muestre en el textview dentro del nav view. Puedes ayudarme? Gracias, saludos.

Comment: En tu pregunta original no existía el método .apply() procura agregar siempre la información correcta